# Submitting form from different <div> HTML

Tags: php, html

i have problem with submitting a form using 2 defferent div(tabs). I want to submit all the value from this form.. but when i submit, the value that i receive only from (div class="tab1") not from div class="tab2". how can i submit all the value even using different div

page.php

```
<div class="tab1">
<h2>Basic Information</h2>
<form name="pages_details" method="post" action="pages/save_pages.php">
<table>  
    <tr>  
        <td>Name:</td>  
        <td><input name="name" type="text" ></input></td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td>Order:</td>  
        <td><input name="ord" type="text"></input></td>  
    </tr> 
</table>
</div>
<div class="tab2">
<h2>Additional Information</h2>
<table>  
 <tr>  
    <td>Special:</td>  
    <td><input name="special" type="text" ></input></td>  
 </tr> 
 <tr>  
    <td>Title:</td>  
    <td><input name="title" type="text"></input></td>  
 </tr> 
</table>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
</form>
```

save_pages.php

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$ord = $_REQUEST['ord'];
$special = $_REQUEST['special'];
$title = $_REQUEST['title'];

echo $name;
echo $ord;
echo $special;
echo $title;
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you put the first div within the form tag?  You really shouldn't overlap them like that.

Comment: Use the `form` and not the (presumably display) `div` to submit your values?

Comment: @Alex : do you mean put the div tag inside the form tag? i already tried that but it make the tab not functioning.

Comment: @Jared : can u give me example for that?

Comment: @hemiz yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: `form` elements usually wrap the entire context, so put them on the outside of all the other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make sure you close tags in the right order.
Structuring code like this can cause some weird bugs.

**Not right:**

```
<div>
<form>    
</div>
</form>
```

So you might want to do it like this.

```
<form>
<div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I edited your answer since I almost misinterpreted your answer.

Comment: @jared  <form><div class="tab1"></div><div class="tab2"></div></form>. i make it like this but still cannot functioning

Comment: @hemiz - That's a valid, mostly beside-the-point example markup.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use jquery ajax to submit the form based on your case.

For example:

```
var datas = $(form).serialize();
$.post("pages/save_pages.php", datas, function(){

});
```

Referring:
post - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
serialize - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/