# Only getting one element from html array in my php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, forms

I have a select in my HTML form:

```
<form name="correo" id="correo" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="<!--return checkFields();-->" ><div class="multi-field-wrapper" name="multi-field-wrapper">
                    <div class="multi-fields" name="multi-fields">
                        <div class="multi-field" name="multi-field">
                            <div>
                                <label for="penviadas[]"> Cantidad </label>
                                <input type="number" name="penviadas[]" class="penviadas" id="penviadas" maxlength="70" placeholder="¿Cuántas?" onClick="removerIcon('iconcant');" > 
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="add-field">Añadir otra referencia</button>
                </div>
```

And I can add fields dynamically (or what's the same, I can repeat the code above many times; the code below works).

```
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
  $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
  });
  $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
      $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
  });
});
```

Let's say I have 3 different selects (`penviadas`). What I want is to get all of them in my PHP file once I submit the form. **It used to work**, but now, for some reason, I can only get THE FIRST select (`penviadas`). Why am I not getting all the values from `penviadas` array?

PD: I print it in my PHP in different ways but they all return ONLY THE FIRST ELEMENT from `penviadas`, not the rest:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST['penviadas']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after many hours playing stupid.
With the information in the OP it was impossible to discover where there was a problem. I found the solution here: [Submitting form from different <div> HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821803/submitting-form-from-different-div-html)

Basically, I had this structure:

```
<div...
<form...
</div...
</form>
```

I thought it was alright and didn't think for a moment this could be affecting. Thus, it wasn't the PHP/JS but the html tags that were incorrect. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test']))
{
$data = $_POST['referenciasnuevas'];
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
}
}
?>
```

Html Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="#">
<div class="multi-field-wrapper" name="multi-field-wrapper">
<div class="multi-fields" name="multi-fields">
<div class="multi-field" name="multi-field">
<label for="referenciasnuevas[]">Referencia pieza</label>
<select name="referenciasnuevas[]" id="referenciasnuevas" class="referenciasnuevas" style="width: 105px"  onClick="removerIcon('iconref');">
<option selected value='-1'> ¿cliente? </option></select>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="add-field">Añadir otra referencia</button>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="test" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
$(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
});
$('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
        $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works for me.please look my code

Comment: I've tried your code and indeed, it works. However, when I embed it into my form, it doesn't. I will edit the first question with a more simple part of my code which has the same problem. Maybe you can find why your form works in my page but not if I put it into my own form? Thanks a lot

Comment: No, but I already posted the answer. It was a malformed div. Thanks